# XAML Image source not work in cross-platform (Android emulator)

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to design a UI similar to Instagram (it's an exercise) and there's no way to show the image from URL. It seems that the code is correct but it doesn't work.

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Text="nyc_photographer"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <!--Image not showing-->
    <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/3/"/>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
        <Button TextColor="Blue" Text="Like" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
        <Button TextColor="Blue" Text="Comment" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        <Button TextColor="Blue" Text="Share" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
     </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout>        
        <BoxView Color="#f0f0f0" HeightRequest="1" />
        <Label Text="700 likes" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label TextColor="#444" Text="This is a shot yesterday in Skanor, Sweden, when driving home, from a couple of days of work in Denmark." />
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

After nickname nyc_photographer and Like button shoud appear the image.
I show an image of how the expected result should be.

[image: I show an image of how the expected result should be.]

Comment: does your app have internet permissions enabled?  Have you verified that the image url is able to load in the device's browser?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively that seems to be the problem ... 
My AVD has no internet conexion but the laptop does have

I solved the problem starting emu with cmd command.
%AppData%\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>**emulator.exe -avd *avdname* -dns-server 8.8.8.8**

[image]